# Function inside foreach in javascript and variable scope

Tags: javascript, foreach, scope

I need something similar to this:

```
"use strict"

var arrayToFill = new Array();
var arrayWithData = ["a", "b", "c"];

arrayWithData.forEach(function(entry) {

     arrayToFill[entry] = "something";
});
```

<s>Looks like</s> My NetBeans says, that I have problem with `arrayToFill` variable scope. I can't access it from `function(entry)`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Within the `forEach` loop, `console.log(arrayToFill, entry);` should give you some insight.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  `entry` should close over `arrayToFill` in the code you've provided.

Comment: Not reproducible. You should use an object instead of an array, though.

Comment: `arrayToFill ` should be initialized as `object` right ?

Comment: @DavinTryon There is no error message. NetBeans says, that `arrayToFill[]` is not defined inside my foreach loop.

Comment: Worked fine with me, no issue here.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your scope here.

You are just trying to assign values to the `a`, `b` and `c` **properties** of the array — which doesn't make sense because arrays are designed to hold *ordered* data with *numerical* property names.

If you then `console.log` the result, it will show up as an **empty array** because that only reveals data with numerical indexes. This is probably what is causing you to think you have the scope wrong.

You can access the data just fine like this:

```js
"use strict"

var arrayToFill = new Array();
var arrayWithData = ["a", "b", "c"];

arrayWithData.forEach(function(entry) {
console.log(entry);
     arrayToFill[entry] = "something";
});

alert(arrayToFill.a);
```

You probably want to be using an object and not an array.

```
var nonArrayToFill = {};
```